# Internet Explorer not writing to document.cookie?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, iframe, cookies

Ran into something lovely, and intermittent, while trying to write cookies today in an *Iframe*  via javascript.

So say I assign a new cookie:

```
document.cookie = "key=value;";
```

Calling said cookie returns as:

```
document.cookie = "";
```

I've tried this across both IE 9 and IE10, and it's working for some users, and not others.  Same browser versions.

Furthermore, it seems to be machine specific, we're in an enterprise network, and users can log into one machine, and be okay, whilest another station and we'll see this behavior.

I've thought about some group policy, but that last point has me at something of a loss.

**Edit:  More extra details.**

Cookies are allowed on these machines.

This isn't a Session/Persistent Cookie mix up; literally trying to write to the document.cookie object returns "", even if you call it right after assignment.

Here's a big one I missed, I'm trying to assign these as an *Iframe*, and there doesn't seem to be an issue with P3P headers, as there are machines that are viewing it just fine; same browser versions.

Comment: An obvious first thing to check is if cookies are disabled in the browser on that machine.

Comment: No, cookies are not disabled.

Comment: What is the privacy level setting on the browsers which are not setting the cookie?

Comment: Same as the others, Medium.  Which would answer my questions if other machines weren't able to successfully use cookies.

Answer (score 2):

I was experiencing the same problem and found that the users with IE that could not take the cookie had protected mode enabled.

Internet Options/Security/Enable Protected Mode (uncheck)